# The log files are empty

Tags: linux, logging, syslog

I found out that my /var/log/messages is empty!

Also my /var/log/auth.log is also empty!

Also it is not logging any messages.

My `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file is as follows:

```
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#                       For more information see
#                       /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html
#
#  Default logging rules can be found in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
#module(load="immark")  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")

# provides TCP syslog reception
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")

# Enable non-kernel facility klog messages
$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on

###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Filter duplicated messages
$RepeatedMsgReduction on

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

$AllowedSender TCP, 192.168.1.0/24





$template HostAudit, “/var/log/rsyslog/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%HOSTNAME%_audit.log”
$template auditFormat, “%msg%\n”  local6.*      ?HostAudit;auditFormat
```

What is the problem here?

**Edit1**

My `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` is as follows:

```
#  Default rules for rsyslog.
#
#                       For more information see rsyslog.conf(5) and /etc/rsyslog.conf

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
#daemon.*                       -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
#lpr.*                          -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
#user.*                         -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
#mail.info                      -/var/log/mail.info
#mail.warn                      -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err

#
# Logging for INN news system.
#
news.crit                       /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err                        /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice                     -/var/log/news/news.notice

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
#*.=debug;\
#       auth,authpriv.none;\
#       news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
#*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
#       auth,authpriv.none;\
#       cron,daemon.none;\
#       mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg                                :omusrmsg:*

#
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
#
#daemon,mail.*;\
#       news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
#       *.=debug;*.=info;\
#       *.=notice;*.=warn       /dev/tty8

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
#
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
        news.err;\
        *.=debug;*.=info;\
        *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
```

Comment: Have you checked your `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` configuration? In my Ubuntu 16.04.4, `messages` is disabled, though `auth.log` is working.

Comment: Your configuration also has `messages` commented out.

Comment: In what lines should I remove the comments?

Comment: `#*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\ ` and the next 3 lines: these constitute the only statement that configures `/var/log/messages`.

Answer (score 1):

we had this issue also. After an update to Debian 9 in 2018-06, rsyslogd was no longer writing to logfiles.

By running

```
service rsyslog status
```

We found that the file

```
/etc/rsyslog.d/named.conf
```

wasn't being read properly, and therefor prevented rsyslogd from running at all.

We didn't need specific Bind9 (DNS) logging so we moved the file to an extension that wouldn't be loaded:

```
mv /etc/rsyslogs/named.conf /etc/rsyslogs/named.conf.bak
```

After restarting rsyslogd

```
service rsyslog restart
```

the auth.log and other files are now working as expected.